# SilverStripe 'None of these templates can be found in theme 'default'

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a widget which has two templates. EligibilityWidget.ss and EligibilityWidget_ShortForm.ss .

I am running this code

```
public function init() {
    $cookie = (Cookie::get('__utmz'));

    if (isset($cookie)) {
        return $this->renderWith('EligibilityWidget_ShortForm');
    } else {
        return $this->renderWith('EligibilityWidget');
    }
}
```

This should identify if the cookie exists and render the information with the correct template. However, when I run this I get the error message:

> [User Warning] None of these templates can be found in theme
>   'default': Widget.ss, DataObject.ss, ViewableData.ss, Object.ss

I have also tried changing a line of code to

```
return $this->renderWith(array('EligibilityWidget_ShortForm', 'Widget'));
```

However this also returned the same error. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: just to make sure - did you flush after you created the templates? like domain.tld?flush and if you did so, does it show up if you have the templates in your project vs. your theme-folder? (flush again after moving files!)

Comment: Yes I flushed, also I have tried your suggestion of trying the template in both locations and flushing, however this returns the same error message.

Comment: Are there any empty widget instances in your blog holder or blog page? If there are, delete those.

Comment: What does your theme folder structure look like? I've found some modules can be picky about the templates files when nesting in subfolders of the `templates` folder.